# The remote name could not be resolved: Error adding third party webservice to my web application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I'm getting an error while trying to download the wsdl file from the third party url.

**Error:**

```
There was an error downloading 'https://xxxxx.com/wsdl/Object/CustomObjectInstances?Id=xxxx'.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'xxx.xxxx.xxx'
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://xxxxx.com/wsdl/Object/CustomObjectInstances?Id=xxxx'.
There was no endpoint listening at https://xxxxx.com/wsdl/Object/CustomObjectInstances?Id=xxxx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'xxx.xxxx.xxx'
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

**My findings :**

1.I have build the solution and try to adding the service ref (same error) .
2.The IP which is in the error seems odd (xxx.xxxx.xxx).having only three parts.

Comment: If the message is correct and you don't have network related problems, you will have to ask your third party about it, it's not a technical problem you can solve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762322/add-service-reference-is-failing-in-vs

Comment: @nvoigt.using the same url one of my team member can download the Wsdl.Do i need to change any visualstudio props?

Comment: If it downloadable by others, in that case can you check if there is any firewall/a different proxy to make sure nothing is blocking the request?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan, But I am able to put the url in IE and able to see the service details(XML).Then is still a firewall problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with my IE settings.

**IE --> Tools -- >Internet options --> connections -->Lan Settings**

**old one** - wrong one which is cause for the problem.

'xxx.xxxx.xxx' - 3 parts

**Changed to**

'xxx.xx.xx.xxx' - 4 parts

Answer (score 0):

Add write permission on C:\Windows\Temp for Application Pool user, It should resolve your issue.

Refer this [blog](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/raimondb/archive/2008/02/14/Unable-to-generate-a-WCF-proxy-using-svcutil-but-retreiving-the-wsdl-works_3F00_.aspx)

Possible duplicate of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358977/unable-to-reference-wsdl-of-wcf-web-service-hosted-on-appfabric)

Comment: @LaksmiNarayanan ,This is not solving my issue.